# addClass isn't working within a click function

Tags: jquery, click

In the `head` of my script, I define a click function for the class `ActiveQuestionCycler`, which cycles through a series a panels. (Full code for this function at the bottom of this post.) When I assign that class to a div element (e.g. `<div class="ActiveQuestionCycler"></div>`), the function works, so there are no errors in this code.

In addition, I can successfully use the following code to add the class `activequestioncycler` to a new div element (`<div class="NewDiv"></div>`) so that it, too, runs the `activequestioncycler` function when I click on it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".NewDiv").addClass("ActiveQuestionCycler");
});
</script>
```

However, I am having trouble adding the class to one div element (e.g. `<div class="DivToClick"></div>`) when another (e.g. `<div class="DivToAdoptClass"></div>`) is clicked.

***Here's the code that isn't working***:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".DivToClick").click(function () {
    $(".DivToAdoptClass").addClass("ActiveQuestionCycler");
});
</script>
```

If I click `DivToClick` it should add the `ActiveQuestionCycler` class to `DivToAdoptClass` so that, if I subsequently click `DivToAdoptClass`, it will run the function and show the panels. However, nothing happens.

If I use something other than `addClass`, the function above works fine. For example, the following function successfully hides `DivToAdoptClass` when I click `DivToClick`

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".DivToClick").click(function () {
    $(".DivToAdoptClass").hide();
});
</script>
```

If someone could help explain why `addClass` doesn't work when it runs within a click function, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

**JUST IN CASE: CODE THAT DEFINES CLICK FUNCTION FOR `ACTIVEQUESTIONCYCLER` CLASS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var controlPanel = [] 
var questiontype= '<?php echo $data['QuestionType']; ?>'
         var panels=$("."+questiontype+"Question."+questionlevel+".active").length;     

    $(".ActiveQuestionCycler").click(function () {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*panels);
      if (controlPanel.length >= $("."+questiontype+"Question."+questionlevel+".active").length) { 
        controlPanel.length = 0 
      }
      while (controlPanel.indexOf(rand) !== -1){ 
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*panels);
      }
      controlPanel.push(rand) 
        for(i=1;i<=panels;i++){
if($("."+questiontype+"Question."+questionlevel+".active").is(":visible")){
                $("."+questiontype+"Question."+questionlevel+".active").hide();
            }
        }   
        setTimeout(function(){
 $("."+questiontype+"Question."+questionlevel+".active").eq(rand).show();
    });   
});
</script>
```

Comment: @adeneo I read through the post that this is supposedly a duplicate of and I don't understand how I would apply that to this particular case. Any help would be much appreciated. Also, why would this work for `hide` and not for `addClass`

Comment: I've been playing around with this more and it seems as though the issue lies in the code that defines what happens when an element with class `ActiveQuestionCycler` is clicked. It fails to recognize that there's a new element with that class.

Comment: When you bind an event handler it's bound to all matching elements at that time. When you add a class a later, the previously bound event handler won't work for that element. This seems to be the issue here, and you'll need delegated event handlers -> https://jsfiddle.net/x3pk4ek2/